# React admin tree hierarchy and collapse buttons do not appear

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I'm having a hard time trying to make ra-tree-ui-materialui work following this doc :
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-tree-ui-materialui/README.md
I already have a react-admin backoffice with some fixture data, and I decided, after editing my App.js like explained in link above, to put my tree logic inside SegmentationList.js, which manages display of all Segmentations coming from an APIPlatform backend.

I commented datagrid logic already present in file, to test the tree alone. I kept all imports active and added those needed for the tree like in docs. With this code I manage to have the tree displayed, but with no hierarchy view at all, even when I set a row as child of another by editing, or when I do it via drag and drop.

When I try the latter, I actually view the child row nested inside its parent with collapse button for a few seconds only. Then it comes back to a flat tree.

I have tried to disable JSS in the file to see if style was guilty. I checked if react-dnd was installed and it is. I checked that parent field had value expected in child row by coming back to its edit page. Finally I went to backend side to check if parent field values in DB were consistent with what I saw in frontend, it was. Finally I had a look on this topic : https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2980 since I also have the warning *"Missing translation for key: "ra.tree.root_target""*.
Thanks for your help.

First, here is my App.js file :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource, mergeTranslations } from 'react-admin';
import { reducer as tree } from 'ra-tree-ui-materialui';
import englishMessage from 'ra-language-english';
import treeEnglishMessages from 'ra-tree-language-english';

import parseHydraDocumentation from '@api-platform/api-doc-parser/lib/hydra/parseHydraDocumentation';
import { hydraClient  } from '@api-platform/admin';
import Locale from "./Resources/Locale/"
import Segmentation from "./Resources/Segmentation/"
import SegmentationTranslation from "./Resources/SegmentationTranslation/"
import Product from "./Resources/Product/"
import Attribute from "./Resources/Attribute/"
import ProductTranslation from "./Resources/ProductTranslation/"
import translations from './i18n';
import CustomRoute from './routes';
import themeReducer from './themeReducer';
import { Layout } from './layout';
import LocaleRetrieve from './Utils/LocaleRetrieve';

const messages = {
    'en': mergeTranslations(englishMessage, treeEnglishMessages),
};

const dataProvider = api => hydraClient(api);

const httpEndpoint = process.env.REACT_APP_XXX_HTTP;

const apiDocumentationParser = httpEndpoint => parseHydraDocumentation(httpEndpoint)
    .then(
        ({ api }) => ({api})
    );

const i18nProvider = locale => {
    // change of locale after initial call returns a promise
    return translations[locale];
}

export default class extends Component {
    state = { api: null };

    componentDidMount() {
        apiDocumentationParser(httpEndpoint).then(({ api }) => {
            this.setState({ api });
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
        console.log(LocaleRetrieve());
    };

    render() {
        if (null === this.state.api) return <div>Loading...</div>;
        return (
            <Admin api={ this.state.api }
                   apiDocumentationParser={ apiDocumentationParser }
                   dataProvider= { dataProvider(this.state.api) }
                   customReducers={{theme: themeReducer, tree}}
                   messages={translations}
                   locale="en"
                   i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
                   title="XXX"
                   customRoutes={CustomRoute}
                   appLayout={Layout}

            >

                <Resource name="locales" {...Locale} />
                <Resource name="segmentations" {...Segmentation} />
                <Resource name="segmentation_translations" {...SegmentationTranslation}/>
                <Resource name="products" {...Product}/>
                <Resource name="product_translations" {...ProductTranslation}/>
                <Resource name="attributes" {...Attribute}/>
            </Admin>
        )
    }
}
```

and here is my component with tree logic, located in src/Resources/Segmentation/SegmentationList.js :

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import {List, Datagrid, TextField, ChipField, BooleanField, ReferenceField, EditButton, ReferenceInput, AutocompleteInput, ShowButton, Filter, TextInput, Labeled, CardActions, ExportButton, RefreshButton, DeleteButton, SaveButton } from 'react-admin';
import LinkToTranslatations from './LinkToTranslations';
import AddChildButton from "./AddChildButton";
import ListChildButton from "./ListChildButton";
import PublishedButtons from './PublishedButtons';
import CreateSegmentationButtons from './CreateSegmentationButtons';
// for tree
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { IgnoreFormProps, Tree, NodeForm, NodeActions, NodeView } from 'ra-tree-ui-materialui';

const styles = {
    hash: {
        marginLeft: '15px',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginRight: '15px'
    },
    type: {
        marginLeft: '15px',
        marginRight: '15px',
        textTransform: 'uppercase'
    },
    title: {
        marginLeft: '15px',
        marginRight: '15px'
    }
};

// for tree
const SegmentationTreeActions = props => (
    <NodeActions {...props}>
        <LinkToTranslatations />
        <ShowButton />
        <IgnoreFormProps>
            <EditButton />
            <DeleteButton />
        </IgnoreFormProps>
    </NodeActions>
);

// tree
export const SegmentationList = withStyles(styles)(({ classes, ...props}) => (
    <List {...props} perPage={10000}>
        <Tree allowDropOnRoot enableDragAndDrop>
            <NodeView actions={<SegmentationTreeActions />}>
                <TextField source="hash" className={classes.hash} />
                <TextField source="type" className={classes.type} />
                <TextField source="title" className={classes.title} />
            </NodeView>
        </Tree>
    </List>
));

export default SegmentationList;
```